# Contador no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla con diferentes alimentos y por cada alimento un checkbox. 
Quiero que por cada alimento seleccionado se vayan sumando sus kcals y mostrarlas al final. 
Las kcals de cada alimento son de tipo double.
He hecho el siguiente código pero no sigue sumando el resto de alimentos solo el primero y además no suma bien.

Función para calcular la suma:

```
function contador(checkbox,kcal) {
    caloriasT = 0;
    if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
        caloriasT+=kcal;
    }else{
        caloriasT=caloriasT-kcal;
    }
    $("#kcals").html(caloriasT);
}
```

Checkbox que llama a la función:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" 
        onclick="cambiarEstado(this,'{{$alimentoid}}','{{$cantidadid}}','{{$comentarioid}}');
        contador(this,'{{$a->kcal}}')"
    >
</td>
```

Párrafo donde se muestra la suma:

```
<div class="row" style=" padding-left: 25px;">
    <p class="text-left col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="font-size:18px;width:250px;">
        <strong>Kcals seleccionadas: </strong>
    </p>
    <p class="text-left col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="font-size: 18px" id="kcals">

    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Suma mal porque cada vez que llamas a contador inicializa la variable calorias a 0

Comment: Corregido esa parte gracias! Pero sigue sin funcionar va poniendo cada cantidad una detrás de otra como si entendiera que son cadenas en lugar de números. ¿Debería parsearlas?

Comment: Voy a intentar hacer una arreglo

Comment: Eso es porque le pasas las calorías como una variable de tipo string, deberías convertir los valores a formato numérico con 'parse.Int()' o 'parse.Float()' según el formato que estés usando.

Comment: Eso es tienes que hacer como ha dicho @Eduardorq

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias a ambos :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function contador(checkbox,kcal) {
caloriasT = 0;
if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
    caloriasT+=parseFloat(kcal);
}
$("#kcals").html(caloriasT);
}
```

No debes restar los valores. Como cada vez que haces la llamada pones caloriasT  a cero, no es necesario que restes nada, solo sumar los que estén checked.

Ademas pon los valores como NUMERO, no como string.